# Frontend shows "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" redirect to https in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i have migrated live site to localhost using following plugin 
"Duplicator – WordPress Migration Plugin" backend works fine but frontend show errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you dont have https enabled on your localhost, change your default site name to http:// instead of https:// in the site confg settings